# Find path to folders that does not have a certain subfolder in its path

Tags: regex, bash

Say that I have this folder structure:

```
a/b/test/
a/b/c/test/
a/b/d/test/
```

I want to write a bash script that returns this:

```
a/b/test/
a/b/d/test/
```

Currently I am experimenting with `find`

`find . -regex ".*/test"` but this returns everything.

`find . -regex "[^c]"` this returns nothing

What I want is something like `find . -regex "(?!c)"` but I cant use lookbacks in bash

I could also do something like

```
if [[${pwd} == *"c"*]]; then
    dont include in output
fi
```

But with this last example I am not quite sure if this will be compatiable on both linux and windows and/or if this is a "good" way.

How would you do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this `find`:

```
find . -type d -path '*/test' -not -path '*/c/*'
```

**`find` command Details:**

- `.`: Match from current path
- `-type d`: only directories
- `-path '*/test'`: Match paths that have `/test` in the end
- `-not -path '*/c/*'`: But don't have `/c/` anywhere in the middle

Comment: OP may use `!` instead of `-not` to make it: `find . -type d -path '*/test' ! -path '*/c/*'`

Comment: How do you mean that its not portable? I was able to run this on both my windows and linux computer? Thanks